Technical term for a part of a tensor product of spaces.
Consider a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}= \otimes_i \mathcal{H}_{i}$. Consider two factor spaces $\mathcal{H}_S,\mathcal{H}_F \in \{\mathcal{H}_1, \mathcal{H}_2, \dotsc ,\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2, \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_3,\dotsc ,\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2 \otimes \mathcal{H}_3 ,\dotsc\}$.
Define the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{H}-\mathcal{H}_S, \mathcal{H}_F}$ as the Hilbert space composed by all of the factor spaces in $\mathcal{H}$, apart from the factors inside of $\mathcal{H}_S$ and $\mathcal{H}_F$. Is there a technical name for $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{H}-\mathcal{H}_S, \mathcal{H}_F}$ ? Or a more appropriate and simpler way to put this?
For example, suppose $\mathcal{H}= \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{H}_7$ and $\mathcal{H}_S= \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_3$ and $\mathcal{H}_F=\mathcal{H}_6 \otimes \mathcal{H}_7$. Then $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{H}-\mathcal{H}_S, \mathcal{H}_F}= \mathcal{H}_2 \otimes \mathcal{H}_4 \otimes \mathcal{H}_5$.

Would it suit your context if you just wrote $\mathcal{H}_{(S \cup F)^c}$?

To expand on Lee's comment, for every subset $S \subseteq I$ of the indexing set $I$ we define $\mathcal{H}S := \bigotimes{i \in S} H_i$. Then, literally, what you do here is the construction of $\mathcal{H}_{I \setminus (S \cup F)}$ for two subsets $S,F \subseteq I$. Not sure why there should be a special name for this.

That’s perfect, thank you. I didn’t quite manage to express it so neatly, but that’s perfect.
